# Calcular muestra en Pseint

Tags: c++, pseint

Tengo el siguiente codigo en c++, requiero generarlo en Pseint, pero tengo problemas al generar la operación matematica para calcular el valor de n: `n = ((pow(Z,2)*p*q*N)/(pow(E,2)*(N-1)+pow(Z,2)*p*q));`

Codigo C++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {

float N, Z, p,q,E, n = 0;

cout <<"Ingresa el nivel de la poblacion (N): "; cin>>N;
cout <<"Ingresa el nivel de confianza (Z): "; cin>>Z;
cout <<"Ingresa el nivel de estimacion de error (E) : "; cin>>E;
cout <<"Ingresa probabilidad de que SI ocurra evento estudiando (P): "; cin>>p;
cout <<"Ingresa probabilidad de que NO ocurra evento estudiando (Q): "; cin>>q;

      n = ((pow(Z,2)*p*q*N)/(pow(E,2)*(N-1)+pow(Z,2)*p*q));
      
      cout.precision(4);

     cout <<"n\ El tamaño de muestra es:" <<n;

    return 0;
}
```

Codigo Pseint

```
Proceso Muestra_MIFV

Definir rN, N, rZ, Z, rp, p, rq, q, rE, E, n Como Real;
n <- 0;
    
Escribir "Ingresa el nivel de la poblacion (N):"; Leer  N;
Escribir "Ingresa el nivel de confianza (Z): "; Leer Z;
Escribir "Ingresa el nivel de estimacion de error (E) : "; Leer E;
Escribir "Ingresa probabilidad de que SI ocurra evento estudiando (P): "; Leer p;
Escribir "Ingresa probabilidad de que NO ocurra evento estudiando (Q): "; Leer  q;
```

Entiendo que es realmente sencillo, pero no encuentro como ejecutar esa operación en Pseint,

¿Me pueden apoyar?

Se los agradeceria mucho,

Saludos

Comment: No entiendo. en C elevas el numero al cuadrado pero en pseint sacas la raiz. ¿Por que?

Comment: Tienes razón...

Comment: Vaaaaaa markdown es fastidioso al poner signo de multiplicacion.

Comment: Y que resultados obtienes a poner esta formula:

Comment: n<-(((Z* * *Z)* * *p* * *q* * *N)/((E* * *E)* * *(N-1)+(Z* * *Z)* * *p***q))

Comment: Por favor quita los signos sobrantes.

Comment: Muchas gracias Daniel, quedo así (((Z^2) * p * q * N)/((E^2) * (N-1)+(Z^2) * p * q));

Comment: Lograste algo que yo no: Colocar los signo de multiplicaacion en donde va.

Answer (score 0):

Acá está el código completo. Adicionalmete tiene un SubProceso que le controla la cantidad de cifras que se muestran

```
Proceso Muestra_MIFV
        Definir rN, N, rZ, Z, rp, p, rq, q, rE, E Como Reales;
        n <- 0;
        
        Escribir "Ingresa el nivel de la poblacion (N):"; Leer  N;
        Escribir "Ingresa el nivel de confianza (Z): "; Leer Z;
        Escribir "Ingresa el nivel de estimacion de error (E) : "; Leer E;
        Escribir "Ingresa probabilidad de que SI ocurra evento estudiando (P): "; Leer p;
        Escribir "Ingresa probabilidad de que NO ocurra evento estudiando (Q): "; Leer  q;
        
        n <- (((Z^2)*p*q*N)/((E^2)*(N-1)+(Z^2)*p*q));
        
        Escribir "El tamaño de muestra es: ", Precision(n,4);
    FinProceso
    
    SubProceso result <-Precision (a,x)
        Definir factor Como Entero;
        Definir result Como Real;
        factor <- 10^x;
        result <- trunc(a*factor)/factor;
    FinSubProceso
```